# SoftLayer_Exception_Public): A current price was provided for the upgrade order. Please send a different price to upgrade the item

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am getting this error below when trying to order SAN Disk for existing vm. This has been working fine for last few days and all of a sudden failing.
with error:

> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\softlayer-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\SoftLayer\API.py",
>   line 446, in call_handler
>       return self.call(self._service_name, name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\softlayer-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\SoftLayer\API.py",
>   line 344, in call
>       verbose=self.verbose)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\softlayer-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\SoftLayer\transport.py",
>   line 65, in make_xml_rpc_api_call
>       e.faultCode, e.faultString) SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError:
>   SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): A current price was
>   provided for the upgrade order. Please send a different price to
>   upgrade the item.

What does this even mean? 
Here is the order container>>

```
    {'prices': [{'id': 112927}], 'virtualGuests': [{'id': 15825861}], 'properties': [{'name': 'MAINTENANCE_WINDOW', 'value': '2016-05-17 16:41:45.029000'}], 'categories': [{'categoryCode': 'disk4'}], 'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade'}

    orderClient = SoftLayer.API.Client('SoftLayer_Product_Order', None, username=getUser(detailsFilePath), api_key=getKey(detailsFilePath))

    orderClient.placeOrder(orderContainer)
```

## How did i get price ID:

```
    packageClient = SoftLayer.API.Client('SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest', virtualGuestid, username=getUser(detailsFilePath), api_key=getKey(detailsFilePath))
    items = packageClient.getUpgradeItemPrices()
    for item in items:        
           if  item.get('item')['keyName'] == keyname:                
            return item['id']
```

Comment: Actually i just tried again with a different size disk (250 SAN instead of 200) and it worked. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Would be nice if there was meaningful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that you got:

> "A current price was provided for the upgrade order. Please send a
>   different price to upgrade the item"

Means that the price that you provided is the same as what you already have on the server, you can verify the prices  that already have on your server with the following request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$vsiId/getBillingItem?objectMask=mask[orderItem[order[items]]]

Method: Get
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey and $vsiId with your own information

> Updated

Check item prices categories

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$vsiId/getUpgradeItemPrices?objectMask=mask[categories]

Method: Get
```

> Updated 2

It is necessary to define **categories** inside of each **price**, take a look the example:

```
{'prices': [{'id': 112927, 'categories': [{'categoryCode': "guest_disk4"}]}], 'virtualGuests': [{'id': 15825861}], 'properties': [{'name': 'MAINTENANCE_WINDOW', 'value': '2016-05-17 16:41:45.029000'}], 'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade'}
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBillingItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBillingItem)
- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUpgradeItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is true. I do have a 200G SAN already on the server. So cannot add another 200G disk if I have one already?

Comment: Yes, you can but not as First disk because I think the price: 112927 has first disk as category, you need to verify the categories for the item prices that you provided, see the updated section in my answer to check categories.

Comment: 112927 is for third disk it seems..
`{'itemId': 1223, 'setupFee': '0', 'recurringFee': '10.93', 'categories': [{'id': 92, 'name': 'Third Disk'}], 'laborFee': '0', 'locationGroupId': 545, 'quantity': ''} ` and thats what i am trying to add
`

Comment: 'item
`{'itemId': 1223, 'setupFee': '0', 'recurringFee': '10.93', 'hourlyRecurringFee': '.018', 'oneTimeFee': '0', 'currentPriceFlag': False, 'id': 112927, 'sort': 0, 'item': {'softwareDescriptionId': '', 'capacity': '200', 'description': '200 GB (SAN)','...`

Comment: You should specify the "categories" property inside of each "price", take a look the template in update 2 section in my answer

Comment: Please, let me know if you had success or need further assistance